# Read only access to app store on ios devices

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I restricted the iOS devices of my kids so they cannot install apps. This was necessary because it's not possible to revoke permissions given via family sharing.

Now the app store icon is fully gone. I'd like to get them some kind of read access to the app store.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you turned off the purchase option on each device?

Comment: Does this prevent from installing free apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Restrictions** to disable the ability to purchase apps or to install any apps.  To turn on Restrictions:

Tap `Settings > General`.

Tap `Restrictions`.

Tap `Enable Restrictions` and create a passcode for Restrictions. Don’t forget this passcode. In the future, you'll need your Restrictions passcode to change your settings or to turn off Restrictions.
What you can restrict

If an app or feature is on or if there's a checkmark next to it, anyone using your device can use that app or feature. Otherwise, no one can use that app or feature.

- Apps and features
- Safari
- Camera (also disables FaceTime)
- FaceTime
- iTunes Store
- Apple Music
- Apple Music Radio
- Apple Music Connect (replaces Connect tab with Playlists)
- iBooks Store
- In-App Purchases
- Siri
- AirDrop
- CarPlay (available only with iPhone 5 or later)
- Installing apps
- Deleting apps
- Multiplayer games in Game Center
- Adding Game Center friends
- You can restrict access to YouTube in iOS 5 and earlier.

**Types of content**
 - Ratings
 - Music and podcasts
 - Movies
 - TV shows
 - Books
 - Apps
 - Siri
 - Websites

If you don’t use Touch ID for paid and in-app purchases, you can choose between two options for how often you need to enter your password for these purchases.

Comment: Yes, I know. The question is how to prevent a user from installing apps but give it the chance to search for new apps in the app store and then ask for permission.

Comment: The Restriction steps above should allow you to prevent the user from installing apps.  I did this with both my kids.  I set it up so that they had to 'ask permission' before they could install any app, free or not.